# React Native expo upload:ios issue

Tags: android, ios, upload, expo

I am having an unknown issue while running

sudo expo upload:ios

This the error that comes up for both iOS first and then Android:

Hi All,
I successfully created the first builds for both Android and iOs, but then I wasn’t been able to update them. Here is the error I am getting:

```
**iOS**

Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (/usr/local/turtle-js/node_modules/@expo/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:52:23)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
…
at spawnAsync (/usr/local/turtle-js/node_modules/@expo/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:17:21)
at spawnAsyncThrowError (/usr/local/turtle-js/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/ExponentTools.js:233:45)
at Object.buildAssetArchiveAsync (/usr/local/turtle-js/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/IosAssetArchive.js:82:51)
at
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)



**Android**

[stderr]

  /app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk34/android-shell-app/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
[stderr]

* Try:
[stderr]

Run with --stacktrace
[stderr]

 option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr]

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr]

BUILD FAILED in 1m 32s
832 actionable tasks: 832 executed
Error: ./gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnAsyncThrowError (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/ExponentTools.js:233:45)
    at buildShellAppAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:812:11)
    at <anonymous>
```

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Validate your assets:  iOS for example uploading a 54x60 icon but and it had to be 60x60 or any other valid sizes .

Comment: Thank you, the issue was that iOS does not support transparency files.  Solved.